# Storing function pointers in Union (C)

Tags: c

I have a structure for 'Circle' and 'Triangle'. I'm trying to create a union of two function pointers that point to two functions operating on both structures each. I think the rest should be self explanatory.

The code is as follows:

```
struct Triangle
{
    char color;
    char shade;
    int base;
    int height;
};

struct Circle
{
    char color;
    char shade;
    int radius;
};

void drawCircle(struct Circle* x);
float areaCircle(struct Circle* x);
void drawTriangle(struct Triangle *x);
float areaTriangle(struct Triangle* x);
```

In main() function:

```
typedef union uCircle
{
    void(*draw)(struct Circle*);
    float(*area)(struct Circle*);
}uc;

typedef union uTriangle
{
    void(*draw)(struct Triangle*);
    float(*area)(struct Triangle*);
}ut;

uc(*vtc[2])(struct Circle*);
vtc[0].(*draw) = &drawCircle;
vtc[1].(*area) = &areaCircle;

ut(*vtt[2])(struct Triangle*);
vtt[0].(*draw) = &drawTriangle;
vtt[1].(*area) = &areaTriangle;
```

The kind of errors I'm getting are these:

```
Structs.c:117:9: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
vtc[0].(*draw) = &drawCircle;

Structs.c:118:9: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
vtc[1].(*area) = &areaCircle;
     ^
Structs.c:121:9: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
vtt[0].(*draw) = &drawTriangle;
     ^
Structs.c:122:9: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
vtt[1].(*area) = &areaTriangle;
```

Looks like it's some simple syntactical mistake that I cannot seem to recognize. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a union like a structure? Union can store only one member at a time.

Comment: did you intend to have  `uc (*vtc)(struct Circle*);` declare a variable `vtc` that is a pointer to function returning `ut` and taking a pointer to `struct Circle` as a single parameter? Because that is exactly what you got. *Both* `vtc` nor `vtt` are function pointers. I suspect that wasn't your intent.

Comment: Since the function signatures of draw and area are different (void vs float), I can't simply create a function pointer array (of one type). To make it work, I'm trying to create a union of these 2 function pointers. This union is to be the type of the function pointer.

Comment: All of a union's members occupy the same space. When you perform the second assignment (if it even worked) you'd overwrite the first. What you want are two function pointers in your original structs.

Comment: I have modified vtc and vtt to be arrays of the respective union types. There shouldn't be any overwrite problems now, just the syntax error. OP updated.

Comment: And now what happens when you write `vtc[0].draw = drawCircle;` etc. instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing.
Instead of this:

```
uc(*vtc)(struct Circle*);
vtc.(*draw) = &drawCircle;
vtc.(*area) = &areaCircle;
```

you should use this:

```
uc vtc;
vtc.draw = drawCircle;
vtc.area = areaCircle;
```

if you intend to use those function pointers via a normal union variable.

Second thing.
Remember that unions store one member at a time.

So,instead of this

```
vtc.draw = drawCircle;
vtc.area = areaCircle;
```

will have the effect of

`vtc.area = areaCircle;` being accessible and overwriting `vtc.draw`.

In other words, accessing `vtc.draw` after initializing `vtc.area` will result in Undefined behavior and strange things might happen.

If you want both `draw` and `area`, then use a structure instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Assignment of pointer functions don't use any  `*`  so code:

```
 vtc.draw = drawCircle;
```

And your approach is wrong, the `uc` and `ut` variables containing function pointers should be `struct`, not `union`.

I guess that you are trying to re-invent [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

You probably want to define a structure containing functions, that is a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table). Something like

```
struct object;

struct methods_st {
   void (*drawer)(struct object*);
   double (*area)(struct object*);
};

struct object {
   struct methods_st* vtable;
   char color, shade;
};

struct circle {
   struct object head;
   int radius;
};

static void circle_drawer (struct object*oc) {
   struct circle*c = (struct circle*)oc;
   draw_circle_of_radius (c->radius);
}

static float circle_area (struct object*oc);

static struct method_st circle_vtable = { circle_drawer, circle_area };
```

If that is not clear enough, look inside [Gobject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) from GTK.

Comment: The function pointers should be in the original Triangle and Circle structs, in fact.

Comment: I tried it your way and got this:
Structs.c:117:5: error: request for member ‘draw’ in something not a structure or union

Also, using unions is part of the problem definition