# union of value and function pointer

Tags: c, unions

I am struggling with using unions. Why am I unable to pass the function pointer to where the union would be? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: removed a typedef

```
#include <stdio.h>

union U {
    int(*fnPtr)(int);
    int i;
};

enum E {
    OPTION_0 = 0,
    OPTION_1 = 1
};

int multiply_by_two (int x) {
    return 2 * x;
}

int f (int x, enum E e, union U u) {
    switch (e) {
        case OPTION_0:
            /* Return the sum */
            return x + u.i;
        case OPTION_1:
            /* Return 2 * x */
            return u.fnPtr (x);
    }
}

int main (void) {
    int a;
    scanf ("%d", &a);
    int b = f (a, OPTION_1, &multiply_by_two);
    printf ("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030961/storing-function-pointers-in-union-c) question.

Comment: `union U` is not `int(*fnPtr)(int)`. `union U` has a member of that type.

Comment: Sorry, the typedef was an error, was typing from memory :/ I've removed it

Comment: @Z4ckZ3r0 As a rule, **never** retype code.  Just copy and paste what you have running.  A small change can make a big difference between functioning and non-functioning code.

Comment: the posted code, when run through the compiller (gcc) results in: gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" 
: In function ‘main’:
:31:29: error: incompatible type for argument 3 of ‘f’
     int b = f (a, OPTION_1, &multiply_by_two);
:17:5: note: expected ‘union U’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(int)’
 int f (int x, enum E e, union U u) {

: In function ‘f’:
:26:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }

Compilation failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this definition is not valid:

```
union U {
    typedef int(*fnPtr)(int);
    int i;
};
```

You can't have a `typedef` inside of a `struct` or `union`.  Removing the typedef will give you a proper definition:

```
union U {
    int(*fnPtr)(int);
    int i;
};
```

The second problem is here:

```
int b = f (a, OPTION_1, &multiply_by_two);
```

The function `f` expects a `union U`, but you're passing it a `int (*)(int)`.  Those types are not compatible.  Just because the union has a member of that type doesn't mean you can use that type wherever you would use the union.  You need to create a union, set the proper field, then pass that to the function.

```
union U u;
u.fnPtr = multiply_by_two;
int b = f (a, OPTION_1, u);
```

Comment: Just a tiny typo: `typedef` wasn't removed in the second snippet.

Comment: I see, so the union cannot implicitly determine which field is valid, and must be manually assigned. Is there a way to do this implicitly?

Comment: @Z4ckZ3r0 No, there is no implicit conversion between struct and union types and other types

Comment: @Groo Thanks, I missed that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In main function, try this:

```
int main()
{
  ...
  union U myUnion;
  myUnion.fnPtr = &multiply_by_two;
  int b = f (a, OPTION_1, myUnion);
  ...
}
```

And also, the union definition is not correct, you need to remove `typedef`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to other answers: this is usually called a variant data type, and it makes sense to keep the type enum in a `struct`, along with the `union`, since you will be passing it around all the time anyway.

So I would recommend placing both in a `struct`:

```
enum var_type
{
    VAR_INT = 0,
    VAR_FUNC = 1
};

struct variant
{
    // contains the type of the stored value
    enum var_type type;

    // contains the actual value
    union {
        int(*fnPtr)(int);
        int i;
    };    
};
```

And then you can have separate functions for creating each subtype, for simpler instantiation:

```
// wrap the int value in the variant struct
struct variant variant_create_int(int i)
{
    return (struct variant){ .type = VAR_INT, .i = i };
}

// wrap the functino pointer in the variant struct
struct variant variant_create_func(int(*fnPtr)(int))
{
    return (struct variant){ .type = VAR_FUNC, .fnPtr = fnPtr };
}
```

Meaning your `main` would do something like:

```
// create variant of type 'VAR_FUNC'
struct variant var = variant_create_func(&multiply_by_two);
```

and just pass the `var` struct forward.